# Level Selection menu, camera boundary unity 2d

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, touch, boundary, orthographic

My level selection menu scene will be a graphic map. Think level selection similar to candy crush. I have different sprites for different maps that will be instantiated when the user moves the camera to that map. In order for me to achieve this, I scroll/move the camera using touch on it's Y-axis. But the problem is, I'm having a trouble getting the boundary of the map sprite, I already read a lot of solution about this one. Here is my current script. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My camera got stuck when it is near the boundary. Thank you for your help

```
public float scrollSpeed = 10.0f;
     public GameObject[] maps;

     Camera mainCamera;

     private float topBound;
     private float bottomBound;
     private Vector3 pos;
     private SpriteRenderer currentSprite;
     private int mapIndex;
     void Awake () 
     {
         mapIndex = 0;
         mainCamera = Camera.main;
         currentSprite = maps [mapIndex].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
         bottomBound = currentSprite.sprite.bounds.size.y * -1;
         topBound = currentSprite.sprite.bounds.size.y + currentSprite.gameObject.transform.position.y;
     }

     void Update () 
     {
         if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
         {
             Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;

             mainCamera.transform.Translate(0f,-touchDeltaPosition.y * scrollSpeed * Time.deltaTime,0f);

         }

     }

     private float getAxisDelta(float axisDelta,float camMin,float camMax,float bottom,float top)
     {
         //get where edge of camera will have moved if full translate is done
         float boundaryMinPixelsDestination = camMin - Mathf.Abs(axisDelta);
         float boundaryMaxPixelsDestination = camMax + Mathf.Abs(axisDelta);

         Debug.Log("MaxPixels:"+boundaryMaxPixelsDestination+"="+camMax+"+"+Mathf.Abs(axisDelta));
         //check to see if you're within the border
         if ((boundaryMinPixelsDestination <= bottom && axisDelta > 0) ||
             (boundaryMaxPixelsDestination >= top && axisDelta < 0))
         {
             axisDelta = 0;
         }

         return axisDelta;

     }

     private float camBoundPos(string pos)
     {
         float bounds = 0f;
         if (pos == "top")
             bounds = mainCamera.transform.position.y + mainCamera.orthographicSize;
         if(pos == "bottom")
             bounds = mainCamera.transform.position.y - mainCamera.orthographicSize;

         return bounds;
     }
```